# unity WebRequest - Windows security

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrequest, windows-security, windows-defender, unitywebrequest

Hi guys I have problem with Windows Antivirus I downloaded a zip file from the IPFS My code :

```
 using (UnityWebRequest wwwAssetsDownloader = UnityWebRequest.Get(JsonData[3]))
                 {
                     yield return wwwAssetsDownloader.Send();
                     if (wwwAssetsDownloader.isNetworkError || wwwAssetsDownloader.isHttpError)
                     {
                         Debug.Log(wwwAssetsDownloader.error);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         string savePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}.zip", Application.persistentDataPath, "myZipFile");
                         print("Path Zip file : " + savePath);
                         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, wwwAssetsDownloader.downloadHandler.data);
                     }
                 }
```

it works fine if I disable my Windows defender . But if my Windows security is enabled, the file will be blocked or damaged How can I show that the file is not a virus. I can not tell my users to disable their antivirus ! PLEASE HELP , THANKS .

Comment: What is in this zip that might be triggering the defender?

Comment: just unity assetsbundle that I created . have some model and texture

Comment: this is my zip file(Simple assetsbundle) : https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeih4s2sqx3bcktxebkyrwwu4bofcmik4ukvlq5ck32xsnzrl5m3jc4

Comment: Why is it a zip then? Why not keep it as AssetBundle and rather use a [`WebRequestAssetBundle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.html)?

Comment: cause the assetbundle is not one file(3 or 4) and when I create IPFS only one file will be upload to my url .  zip is best option that far as i know